# rows of lights with steel rope (rigging wire) - 12 m between stainless pipe structure and concrete wall

Tags: structural-engineering, design, stresses, steel, masonry

Hello Engineering Stack Exchange.

I have been asked by a friend to hang some lights in a space beneath an arched bridge. The bridge is protected so no holes can be drilled into the arched stone; but the friend wants the cables that will support the lights to be as taught as possible (yippee)

My friend wants to run three lengths of steel cable the length of the space, approximately 12m length. On one side of the space there is a concrete wall in which I plan on anchoring eye bolts using M10 x 120mm masonry anchors. The other side of the space is an existing tubular structure that was anchored into the bridge before it was protected. I plan on anchoring the other side into the tubular structure bolting through the tube with eyebolts.

I have several questions.

- What is the best method for anchoring the eyebolt into the concrete? Should I consider chemical anchors?
- Besides bolting through the tube ; what are other options for bolting into/onto the tube? I also thought about bolting a piece of metal onto the existing tubing and anchoring into it.
- I plan on using 4 or 5mm braided wire with thimbles clamps and tensioners; i plan on overbuilding a bit, but the heavier and larger the cable, the harder to tension it becomes.

The load should only be about 10 kg per cable.

I realize the question and info might be a bit vague; if you have any questions, thoughts or advice i would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!